# Laravel Search Api is not get the result

Tags: laravel

i am creating Laravel Search Api.search the course id relavent course information need to be display.but i got 404
NOT FOUND

In order to search the records i have use the api look like this way for

here this is api display all the information check here

**Api**

```
Route::get('admin/contentapi/search/{course_id}',[ContentsApiController::class, 'search']);
```

**Controller**

**ContentsApiController**

```
public function search(Request $request)
        {
           $data = $request->get('data');
           $contents = Content::where('id', $data)->get();
           return response()->json($contents);
        }
```

Comment: you have get course_id in your search method `public function search(Request $request,$course_id)`

Comment: You have to pass course as an argument to your search method in the `ContentsApiController` like
`public function search(Request $request, $course)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use arbitrary URLs for application, you must call a variable in the input of the method for accessing this parameter.

like this example in route file:

```
Route::get('admin/contentapi/search/{course}',[ContentsApiController::class, 'search']);
```

and in method:

```
public function search(Request $request, $course)
```